# Using templates from outside the src folder in enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

Is it possible to serve a template from outside the source folder in enlive ?

I would like to pickup the templates from my resources/public/templates folder instead of the src/templates folder, how do I do that ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried including the folder that contains your templates in the class path. I believe enlive will look at your classpath to locate the template you specify. 
If the resources/public folder is already in your classpath your template path should be similar to
    (deftemplate template-name "templates/path/to/template" []
     .....)

Comment: Thanks Sid, that works like a charm. Used the following lein option to spec > :resource-paths ["src/main/resource"]

Comment: If you go with the conventions, you won't need to specify a full path; besides, that is verbose and duplicative.

Answer (score 1):

I put all my templates in a file not on the classpath and define them with:

```
(defmacro deftemplate- [name source & rest]
  `(deftemplate ~name (java.io/File. (str "path-to-pages/" ~source)) ~@rest ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is it possible to serve a template from outside the source folder. In my case, it worked without any changes to my configuration; I have my templates in `./resources` and static assets in `./resources/public`.

Note: I'm using the following in my `project.clj`

```
:min-lein-version "2.0.0"
:plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.3"]]
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
               [compojure "1.1.5"]
               [enlive/enlive "1.1.1"]]
```

I refer to `./resources/index.html` like this:

```
(h/deftemplate index-template "index.html"
  [s]
  [:title] (h/content s))
```